# ssh local port forwarding not working when url is redirecting to https

Tags: linux, ssh, ssl, https, redirect

I have a windows 10 home with Linux kali running inside it with vmware virtual machine software.

There is a local website that opens on url https://example.com in linux and has self signed certificate. I have added it's ip entry on `etc/hosts` file so that it opens on example.com.

The /etc/hosts file entry on linux:

```
192.168.49.2    example.com
```

This local website redirects to https url when opened on browser i.e. http://example.com =>>> https://example.com.

The website is hosted on kubernetes with the ingress code given below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: first-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
      - example.com
    secretName: myssl
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: first-service
            port:
              number: 8080
```

(I don't think ingress code is needed in the question but for the sake I gave it.)

The problem is that I cannot do ssh local port fowarding to it from my windows. The ssh script is:

```
ssh -L 9090:example.com:80 kali1@192.168.42.75
```

**I get 404 Not Found nginx error.**

I also tried with 443 port with the following command:

```
ssh -L 9090:example.com:443 kali1@192.168.42.75
```

In this case the error is:

**400 Bad Request
The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx**

I also get error saying "The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted." when opening url - "https://localhost:9090/".

If I remove the redirection then the ssh local port redirection works fine and i am able to open the website on my windows browser with `localhost:9090` url. This problem happens only when their is redirection.

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, when your browser receives the redirect to `https://example.com` it tries to make a new connection to host `example.com` on port 443, the default https port.
So if you wanted this to work you'd need to add a second port forwarding clause for https (eg. `443:example.com:443`) to your ssh command line in addition to the existing one for http (`9090:example.com:80`).

Also, depending on your nginx configuration (which you didn't share), nginx may serve that site only for requests to hostname `example.com`, not `localhost`. So you may either have to add `localhost` as an alias name for the site in the nginx configuration, or add `example.com` with an IPv4 address of `127.0.0.1` to your Windows `hosts` file and use that in your browser.

In the second case, when you enter the URL `http://localhost:9090` (or just `localhost:9090`) into your browser you instruct it to make an http (non-TLS) connection to port 9090, but you are forwarding that port to the https port 443 of the nginx server. So your browser ends up trying to talk http to the port on which nginx wants to talk https.
If you want this scenario to work then you have to tell your browser to talk https instead of http, ie. enter the URL `https://localhost:9090` instead of `http://localhost:9090`.

Note that, as in the first scenario, nginx may (depending on the configuration) only answer to the hostname `example.com`, and answer `404 Not found` if addressed as `localhost`. The fix is the same as described above for the first case.

Comment: I tried with 443 port also but i get error 400 Bad Request The plain HTTP request was sent to HTTPS port
nginx.

Comment: Answer updated to match your updated question.

Comment: I tried your solution but could not get the solution. Here what I trid. I opened 2 command prompts. In the first I ssh - `ssh -L 9090:example.com:80 kali1@192.168.42.75` and in the second i ssh - `ssh -L 443:example.com:443 kali1@192.168.42.75`. Then i tried opening the url on windows chrome browser - `http://localhost:9090/` which gave "404 Not Found". `http://localhost:443/` gave "400 Bad Request". `https://localhost:9090/` gave "This site can’t provide a secure connection". `https://localhost:443/` gave "404 Not Found". Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have also said to add entry for 127.0.0.1 pointing to example.com on windows host file. I have question about this which is why we need this thing since I have done this on my Linux machine where the website is hosting. Also when I remove redirection from the site which opens only port 80 and not 443 so in that case the ssh command `ssh -L 9090:example.com:80 kali1@192.168.42.75` works perfectly and I can open the website with the url `http://localhost:9090` on my windows chrome browser. All this thing done without any entry of 127.0.0.1 pointing to example.com on windows host. Thank you.

Comment: Regarding nginx configuration. The website is hosted on kubernetes. The ingress code is now updated on the question. Thank you.